# Forge not reading my Laravel 5 environment variables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

This should be really easy, but it's not.  Here is the default settings for a MySQL database in Laravel 5.

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

I ran `php artisan env` on the production server and got `production`.  I set my environment variables with the correct keys on Forge.  But when I run `artisan` on the production server, I get an error: 'Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'  The reason I think it's saying password: NO is that an empty string is the default for DB_PASSWORD if the environment variable is not set.

I think what is happening is that Forge is not reading my environment variables and is using the defaults specified.  If I change the values of my environment variables, I get the same error message, which seems to confirm this.  I have restarted the Digital Ocean production server, thinking that would force the server to read the variables.  But nada.  Do I need to do something else in Forge to get it to read the variables.  [Jeffrey Way's Laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/server-management-with-forge/episodes/5) doesn't indicate that I need to.

What's going on here?

Comment: I can see that my environment variables are set correctly under "Edit Nginx Configuration."  So what the bleep is going on?

Comment: Found this post on Laracasts.  https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/environment-variables-returning-blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 5 is not yet in beta.

Taylor has already mentioned in a recent podcast that he'll need to make changes to Forge to accommodate Laravel 5 environmental settings.

I think from memory he mentioned the ability to just edit the `.env` file from Forge.

For now - you should just put all your settings into a `.env` file in the root of your web server and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else finds this and is still experiencing it, the .env on both Laravel 5 and Forge now work. You must however make sure your database credentials are correct. This should work for most of the defaults as of the writing of this post (Laravel 5.2)

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=database_name
DB_USERNAME=forge
DB_PASSWORD=the_provided_password
```